# windRose with Package openair

Tags: r, openair

I am trying to plot Windrose using package openair. I have used a simple code and i am getting the error "Subscript out of bound". I couldn't figure out what the error means. Here, `Obs_WR` is my data and `ws` and `wd` are the column names for wind speed and wind direction respectively.

```
windRose(Obs_WR, ws="ws", wd="wd")
Error in mydata[[wd]] : subscript out of bounds
```

A part of dataframe is as follows :

```
> Obs_WR
         ws          wd
[1,]  3.715714   0.1250627
[2,]  4.491868 351.4789611
[3,]  5.312253 346.4029396
[4,]  6.047143 349.8645344
[5,]  6.071389 329.2137482
....  ........ ...........
[38,] 16.589769 274.0356269
[39,]  8.065556 273.2977654
[40,]  7.953387 130.6359338
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example which reproduce this error?

Comment: i ran just one statement
windRose(Obs_WR, ws="ws", wd="wd")

Comment: We don't have access to `Obs_wr`. Please provide a minimal example which reproduce this error. It will be easier to get help.

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: i have added a small portion of what my data frame (Obs_WR) looks like. @Pascal